# Pytest: How to access command line arguments outside of a test

Tags: python, pytest

I would like to access command line arguments passed to pytest from within a non-test class.

I have added the following to my conftest.py file

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):  # pragma: no cover
  """Pytest hook to add custom command line option(s)."""
  group = parser.getgroup("Test", "My test option")
  group.addoption(
    "--stack",
    help="stack", metavar="stack", dest='stack', default=None)
```

But I can not work out how to access the value passed on the command line.  I have found code on how to access it from a fixture, but I would like to access it from a method or class that is not part of the test case.

Comment: Look the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/argparse.html)

Comment: This is a good question (and it is unrelated to argparse or sys.argv like the only other comments here seem to think), but I did find the answer at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13275738/3100515) question (not the accepted answer, the other one).

Answer (score 4):

You can access the parameters with `sys.argv`.
It will return a list of all the arguemnts you sent wrote when you called using the command line.

For example

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):  # pragma: no cover
  """Pytest hook to add custom command line option(s)."""
  params = sys.argv[1:]
  group = parser.getgroup("Test", "My test option")
  group.addoption(
    "--stack",
    help="stack", metavar="stack", dest='stack', default=None)
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes you could add one more pytest hook `pytest_configure` to your conftest.py as follows:

```
stack = None
def pytest_configure(config):
    global stack
    stack = config.getoption('--stack')
```

Now your argument **stack** is available at global level.