# Can't get pytest command line arguments prior to test execution?

Tags: pytest

I triy to skip particular tests dependent on the value of command-line arguments. I try to get arguments values with `pytest.config.getoption("--some-custom-argument")` like described in this [related question suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15422896/5308983) in the test files and check the arguments values via [`skipif`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/skipping.html?highlight=skip#id1). But `pyest` has no  `config`. And getting argument values via `request.config.getoption("--some-custom-argument")` seems only work in fixture functions. Can I get command line arguments prior to test execution somehow different that I can check them in `skipif` on a file scope level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the tests are collected after the configuration stage and before the test collection (i.e. also before test execution), the `pytest.config` is available at the module levelin test modules. Example:

```python
# conftest.py
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--spam', action='store')

# test_spam.py
import pytest


print(pytest.config.getoption('--spam'))


@pytest.mark.skipif(pytest.config.getoption('--spam') == 'eggs', 
                    reason='spam == eggs')
def test_spam():
    assert True
```

Running with `--spam=eggs` yields:

```
$ pytest -vs -rs --spam=eggs
============================== test session starts ================================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.5, pytest-3.4.1, py-1.5.3, pluggy-0.6.0 -- /data/gentoo64/usr/bin/python3.6
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /data/gentoo64/home/u0_a82/projects/stackoverflow/so-50681407, inifile:
plugins: mock-1.6.3, cov-2.5.1, flaky-3.4.0
collecting 0 items                                                                                                     
eggs
collected 1 item

test_spam.py::test_spam SKIPPED
============================ short test summary info ==============================
SKIP [1] test_spam.py:7: spam == eggs

=========================== 1 skipped in 0.03 seconds =============================
```

Comment: mh, I must have some bug in the test selection logic. I'll accept the answer as soon as fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand the question right, you might want to look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53383793/1852644).

It suggests to use a fixture with a `request` object, and read input argument value from there `request.config.getoption("--option_name")` or `request.config.option.name`.

Code snippet (credit goes to ipetrik):

```
# test.py
def test_name(name):
    assert name == 'almond'


# conftest.py
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--name", action="store")

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def name(request):
    name_value = request.config.option.name
    if name_value is None:
        pytest.skip()
    return name_value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do like that

```
@pytest.mark.skipif(pytest.config.option.some-custom-argument=='foo', 
                    reason='i do not want to run this test')
```

But why not to use mark expressions?

Comment: I want to skip dependent on value not dependent on non-/existence. As gar as this works with your suggestion I am happy.

Comment: @thinwybk If you know the cases you're skipping over are completely irrelevant to the value data dependency it's much cleaner to actually totally remove them in `def pytest_collection_modifyitems(config, items):` by manipulating the items list inplace, which could be accomplished by making a temp list and assigning its values like `items[:] = applicable_items`. That way the test report is a lot cleaner with no skipped items should there be a large volume of them related to the data value.